# Websphere MQ call failed with compcode 2 reason 2397

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I am having issue connecting to a qmgr. the host rejected connection due to cipherspec error for ssl channel on port 1414. The keystore checked out ok. I was able to use openssh to connect to the host and retrieve its keys.

I have tried to enable and disable sslv3. I provided keystore password with and without "" (double quotes). These are connection properties

```
qcf=wmq://aftbusu105.it.companyx.com:1414/?qmgr=MQPLTC010,channel=FUSION.SSL,sslCipherSuite=SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5,transportType=1
reqQ=queue:///FUSIONQL.app.queuename.1_0.Q.PS.REQ
rspQ=queue:///FUSIONQL.app.queuename.1_0.Q.PS.REQ
mep=oneway
connCnt=1
sessCnt=1
numMsgs=1
connInterval=10
msgInterval=10
deliveryMode=1
priority=1
expiration=1
keystore=/path/keystore/m36797q.jks
password=a$tilBe2Flower
alias=m36797q
```

Do you know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if you have FIPs enabled on either the server or the client?  It's possible you are getting error because the ciphersuite
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 is not supported in FIPS mode.  Are you seeing any AMQ errors in your QMGR error logs? 
Also, let us know the MQ version you are using.

Comment: How do I enable FIPs on the client side? I am checking w/ FB team if there are any errors on their side (qmgr).

Comment: I'm not certain that FIPs enablement is the cause of your problem, but you can get more info in the knowledge center  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q012440_.htm?locale=en

Comment: my Fusion Bus team thinks there is a defect in queue discovering software. They think the distributed jar files need to be updated for mq 7.5.0.3-.5